# Ошибка в роботе (парсинг сайтов)

Tags: python-3.x

у меня есть массив ссылок, он достаточно большой, поэтому не выкладываю.

Пишу вот такой код:

```
for i in link:
    print(requests.get(i), i)
```

Он получает ответы, все хорошо, но на одной из ссылки вот такая ошибка:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nalog.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rn77/taxation/taxes/ndfl/nalog_vichet/inv_vichet/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

помогите плз, как решить или написать try/except чтобы он ее пропускал и работал дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам действительно нужно просто пропустить "нерабочую" ссылку, то достаточно сделать так:

```
for i in link:
    try: print(requests.get(i), i)
    except requests.exceptions.SSLError: pass
```

Comment: спасибо большое